# modify iframe attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hello I try to modify width attribute for all iframe

here what I did :

```
var editor = tinymce.get('editor1'); 
var content = editor.getContent();

content = content.replace(/width=".*?"/ig, 'width="660"');
editor.setContent(content);
```

It works but my regex will modify all tag which contain width attribute and what I want is only modify iframe width attribute

Comment: Did you try somethig like `replace(/(<iframe.*)width=".*?"(.*/>), '$1width="660"$2') ? `

Comment: @dloeda You missed the ending `/` and also to escape the `/` for the closing tag

Comment: @LuR Did you try the jquery way : `$('iframe').attr("width", function(index,attr) { //make your replace here })` ? See here for more information : http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function

Comment: @dloeda I tried your partern 
https://jsfiddle.net/vj0ohnav/ but seems there is something wrong

Comment: @LuR I answer you with a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution with regex, but I suggest the other solutions, it's better use the DOM API instead regex.

```js
var str = '<p><iframe src="someurl.com" width="540" height="450" scrolling="yes" style="border: none;"></iframe></p><p> toto </p><p><iframe src="someurl.com" width="540" height="450" scrolling="yes" style="border: none;"></iframe></p>';

str = str.replace(/(<iframe.*?)width="\d+"(.*?<\/iframe>)/gu, '$1width="660"$2');

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would copy the content into a container element and manipulate the DOM, then copy it back into the editor. Like this:

```
var editor = tinymce.get('editor1'); 
var content = editor.getContent();
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = content;

var iframes = container.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(iframes, function(iframe){
    iframe.setAttribute('width','660');
});

editor.setContent(container.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you use `jquery` I would go this way :

```
$('iframe').attr("width", function(index,attr) {
     return 600;
});
```

See : https://jsfiddle.net/vj0ohnav/2/